# How can I stop the delay between the two animations?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Here is a demo of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/HgMB4/72/
My problem is that whenever the animation is done and moves to a new animation it stops and then does the next animation. Is there anyway that I can make that pause between animations go away?? I want the transition to flow so it looks kind of like stars floating around in the sky. Please help!

Javascript-

```
 var main = function () {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('#intro .box').each(function () {
        var originalOffset = $(this).position(),
            $this = $(this),
            tLeft = 0,
            tTop = 0,
            tLeft = w - Math.floor(Math.random() * 900),
            tTop = h - Math.floor(Math.random() * 900);

    $(this).animate({
        "left": tLeft,
            "top": tTop
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'linear'
    })
    $('#intro .box').each(function () {
        var originalOffset = $(this).position(),
            $this = $(this),
            tLeft = 0,
            tTop = 0,
            tLeft = w - Math.floor(Math.random() * 900),
            tTop = h - Math.floor(Math.random() * 900);

        $(this).animate({
            "left": tLeft,
                "top": tTop
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'linear'
        })
    });
});
};
$(document).ready(main);
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use plugin like [crSpline](http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html) and then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // set number of animation sequences and duration range:
    var sequencesNumber = 10,
        minDuration     = 5000,
        maxDuration     = 8000;

    var h = $('#intro').height();
    var w = $('#intro').width();

    // loop through the boxes
    $('#intro .box').each(function () {
        var points = [];
        // create random X,Y destination points for a box:
        for(var i=0; i<sequencesNumber; i++){
            points.push([w-Math.floor(Math.random() * 300), h-Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)]);
        }
        // animate box with random points:
        $(this).animate({
            crSpline: $.crSpline.buildSequence(points)
        // calculate random transistion time for a box:
        },(Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDuration - minDuration + 1)) + minDuration));
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9urogxu/)

Comment: I like how that works except it speeds up. I want it do stay at one constant speed. Any ideas?

Comment: you'll have to normalise the duration of the animation, I mean set a different duration for each animation depending on the distance the "star" travels. The duration you set is static whereas the distance is not, so you end up having "stars" that accelerate on a new animation. You'll have to figure out the maths for that though